# How to detect the user in OpenID Connect provider token endpoint

Tags: java, token, openid-connect, openid

I'm talking about the authorization_code grant type. In the authorization end point of the OpenID Connect provider we gave an authorization code to the relying party and then they make a back channel request (no browser involved) to the token end point with this code.
So the question is, how do I distinguish this user at the token end point? I guess no session exists for this call since it's a back channel request.
What methods can be used to identify the user? Could a stored HashMap in memory with key as authorization_code be the ideal solution?

Comment: This is going to be framework-specific.

Comment: Assuming its a native Java implementation, what is the ideal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing it in a `HashMap` is a solution that does not scale, as internal memory is not shared accross server nodes.

You'll have to store it in some form of persistent store

- a SQL database
- a NoSQL database
- a key value database

Note that you'll not only need to be able to determine the user, for which it was made, but also the client, as clients don't need to authenticate themselves to get a code. Also know that you'll need to be able to determine which scopes are covered by a given code, and to detect double usage of a code, and in case of double usage, to revoke associated access tokens.

On the other hand, you need to be able to easily forget the codes again. They're short term use, and it's no use keeping them around after their ttl.

You'll have similar requirements for storing the access tokens, refresh and id tokens you produce, so it'll make sense to build something which can also be used for those.

Comment: Thank for the reply. However I have not understood this "clients don't need to authenticate themselves to get a code". In what scenario this will occur? In my understanding a relying party contacting authorization end point will force the user to authenticate if no user session exists.

Comment: The client (or relying party) is not the same as the user. The authorization endpoint authenticates the user, and accepts a client_id to identify the client, but not the client_secret.